# High memory usage when opening Powershell prompt

Tags: windows, memory, powershell, power

Whenever I open a Powershell prompt either via the built in shell or through ConEmu, Powershell's memory usage is excessively high - usually around 1.5 Gb.

It's worse opening as an Administrator where it jumps between 1Gb and 2Gb roughly every second.

Removing everything from my `~/Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file has no effect.

Running `[System.Gc]::Collect()` takes memory usage down to ~30Mb and it stays that way.

How can I find out what is causing this high usage? Most Powershell memory advice I can find is to do with high usage when running scripts whereas my shell appears to be doing nothing.

Windows 10, Build 1703.

Comment: I wonder if you can get any useful info with a .NET profiler, e.g. https://bennettadelson.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/using-perfview-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak-2/

Comment: Good idea! The majority of the memory is take up by Reflection - Emit.OpCode, RuntimeMethodInfo. That leaves me none the wiser about what's using reflection though!

Comment: Hm. Loaded modules? Anything custom? `Get-Module` should give you a list of loaded ones. Did this start recently?

Comment: It started a few weeks ago, possibly since I installed Creators Update, but i'm not certain. There's no custom modules, only `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` and `PSReadline` loaded.

Comment: ...I'm out of ideas. I'd suggest raising this [over at the official PowerShell forum](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) too — hopefully they can help.

Comment: There are [a few other profile scripts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) that might be in play; do any of those exist on your system? You might also have a look at the PowerShell process with [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (as admin) to see if there's anything unexpected on the .NET Assemblies tab - [here](https://i.imgur.com/QEpYdG1.png)'s what that looks like on my system, which does not display the high memory usage.

Comment: Nope, no other profile scripts around, but good idea. Thanks for that screenshot - mine is almost identical, except with a second `Microsoft.Powershell.Commands` assembly loaded, I have `Management` and `Utility`. I'm not sure why Management is still hanging around, I removed all other WMF features.

Comment: I am having the same problem, thanks for the tip about GC.Collect. That already made things a bit better for me. :)

Comment: It's good to know I'm not the only person with this issue! Out of interest, have you ever installed WMF (Windows Management Framework) on your PC? It's the only think I can think that might have caused this for me.

Answer (score 3):

The same issue happened to me today, powershell would pause for about 5 seconds on startup. Turned out it was PSReadline's fault. The command history was too big (about 600MB in my case) and clearing that fixed the issue.

You can find the history file here:

`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline`

**Edit**

Maximum history count can be set like so:

`Set-PSReadlineOption -MaximumHistoryCount 1024`

Comment: Thanks @Alireza - I can't test this solution as I've since reformatted my machine and the problem went away, but it sounds like a likely candidate.

Comment: @dig412 Didn't realize the post was a year old.